# How to include the background-cover value in the shorthand background property?

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to set a background-image to stretch to the full extent of a `<div>`'s width and height. The `<div>` will be of variable size, so I am using `background-size: cover;`

```
background: url("../images/bkgnd-sidebar.png") no-repeat left top cover;
```

I cannot figure out how to place it in this shorthand notation and have it work. If I list each property independently, it works fine, but I was hoping for an all-in-one solution.

This works, but is not preferred:

```
background-size:cover;
background-image:url('../images/bkgnd-sidebar.png');
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

According to the [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background), there needs to be a slash separating the backgound-size from the background-position:

**W3C example:**

```
p { background: url("chess.png") 40% / 10em gray  round fixed border-box; }
```

**MDN:**

> This property must be specified after background-position, separated
>   with the '/' character.

Opera also has some information on the background shorthand:

http://dev.opera.com/static/dstorey/backgrounds/background-shorthand.html

Answer (score 38):

Good question this is from W3C http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS_shorthand_reference

So if you want to include the background-size value in the shorthand syntax, you need to:

- Explicitly include background-position values even if these are the
  same as the defaults 
     Write background-position values before background-size values.
     Put a slash in between these two pairs of values.

So you would want to do something like this

```
background: url(http://www.stanford.edu/dept/CTL/cgi-bin/academicskillscoaching/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/test-anxiety.gif) top left / cover no-repeat;
```

See fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/8Up6V/

Answer (score 27):

Here is an example using the asker's parameters that will work. Some of the other answers have overcomplicated the parameters a bit. All that needs done is the `background-size` needs to be separated from the `background-position` by a forward slash `/`:

```
 background: url("../images/bkgnd-sidebar.png") left top / cover no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 5):

The [syntax of (multiple) background shorthand](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background) is:

> background: [ <bg-layer> , ]* <final-bg-layer>
>
> Where
>
> <bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <position> [ /
>   <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> ||
>   <box> || <box>
>
> <final-bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <position> [ /
>   <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> ||
>   <box> || <box> || <'background-color'>
>
> ... If one <box> value is present then it sets both
>   ‘background-origin’ and ‘background-clip’ to that value. If two values
>   are present, then the first sets ‘background-origin’ and the second
>   ‘background-clip’.
>
> - A double bar (||) separates two or more options: one or more of them must occur, in any order.
> - An asterisk (*) indicates that the preceding type, word, or group occurs zero or more times.
> - A question mark (?) indicates that the preceding type, word, or group is optional.

So the in order to include `background-size`, you **must** specify the `background-position` before it and place a `/` in-between.

---

Assuming that you want to crop the image from the center instead of top-left you would write:

```
background: url(...) center / cover;
```

All four examples below use the same image:

```css
h1 {
  font: medium monospace;
}
.test {
  display: inline-block;
}
.test-landscape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
.test-portrait {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
}
.test-lefttop {
  background: url(http://dummyimage.com/400x400/CCC/000000&text=%C3%97) left top / cover;
}
.test-center {
  background: url(http://dummyimage.com/400x400/CCC/000000&text=%C3%97) center / cover;
}
```

```html
<h1>background-position: left top<h1>
<div class="test test-landscape test-lefttop"></div>
<div class="test test-portrait  test-lefttop"></div>

<h1>background-position: center</h1>
<div class="test test-landscape test-center"></div>
<div class="test test-portrait  test-center"></div>
```