# W3Schools Background short command reference

Tags: css

```
CSS Syntax:
background: color position size repeat origin clip attachment image|initial|inherit;
```

With this css rule I got white background:

```
<style>
body
{ 
background: #00ff00 url('smiley.gif') no-repeat fixed cover center; 
}
</style>
```

What's wrong? Any Idea? I try to set background-size cover with short background command?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle: jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Yes, you're using w3schools. Use MDN instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sLD5j/ so i know its ok but not working with cover?

Comment: possible duplicate of [use background "cover" in one declaration shorthand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093252/use-background-cover-in-one-declaration-shorthand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Mozilla reference for background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background):

> background-size: This property must be specified after
>   background-position, separated with the '/' character.

So:

```
background: #00ff00 url('smiley.gif') no-repeat fixed center / cover;
```