# Can I insert background-size: cover into the background shorthand?

Tags: css

I had this:

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

I folded `position` and `repeat` into `background`, but the end results causes the background-size property to be overriden:

```
background-size: cover;
background: no-repeat 50% 50%;
```

Is it possible to folder background-size: cover into the shorthand? I attempted `background: no-repeat cover 50% 50%` but that's invalid.

Comment: http://sixrevisions.com/css/background-css-shorthand/ `... 50% 50% / cover no-repeat;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can include `background-size` in the shorthand but there should be no issue with including it **after** the shorthand statement.

EDIT: This [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093252/use-background-cover-in-one-declaration-shorthand) confirms that you can.

```
background: no-repeat 50% 50% etc;
background-size: cover;
```

The shorthand statement overrides **all** background statements, even ones that haven't been included (or can't be included) in the shorthand statement.