# Background Shorthand

Tags: css

Can these 3 properties be specified in shorthand:

```
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

I don;t want to specify color/url as it's done inline.

Comment: Try an internet search, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).

Comment: @Martin: Reason it's not great is because W3Schools is not W3C. The real W3C specs are pretty great... in terms of being technically accurate anyways.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093252/how-to-include-the-background-cover-value-in-the-shorthand-background-property

Answer (score 2):

I've always found background shorthand a fiddly hassle.

[Have you read the W3C guide](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background), it's not great but gives you a starting point.

See also MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background

Which states the order of arguments (and inital values) is:

> ```
> background-image: none
> background-position: 0% 0%
> background-size: auto auto
> background-repeat: repeat
> background-origin: padding-box
> background-clip: border-box
> background-attachment: scroll
> background-color: transparent
> ```

So; you have :

- background-position: center;
- background-repeat: no-repeat;
- background-size: cover;

So list them in order:

```
   background: center / no-repeat cover;
```

**The slash is important for the compiler to know which is which!** (Read the W3C or MDN link above)